# How do I change react-navigation/drawer item "onPress" behavior?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-drawer

I have a stack navigator nested inside a drawer navigator.

```
<HomeDrawerNavigator.Screen 
    name='Restaurants'
    component={RestaurantsStackNavigator}
/>
<HomeDrawerNavigator.Screen 
    name='Settings'
    component={SettingsNavigator}
/>
```

and

```
//RestaurantsStackNavigator
<RestaurantsNavigator.Screen 
    name='Menu'
    component={MenuScreen}

/>
<RestaurantsNavigator.Screen 
    name='MenuProductsDetail'
    component={MenuProductsDetailScreen}
/>
```

I want that when pressing the "Restaurants" button in the drawer to navigate to the first screen of the stack `MenuScreen`, even if the Restaurants item is already selected in the drawer.

Example: In the drawer, the Restaurants item is selected, and I'm in the `MenuProductsDetailScreen`. I want that when pressing the "Restaurants" button inside the drawer (that is already focused), to navigate to the `MenuScreen`.

I can use the `StackActions.replace()` function, but I don't know how to change the default behavior when pressing on a drawer item. Also any other workarounds are welcomed.